# CUBLAS: Incorrect inversion for matrix with zero pivot

Tags: cuda, matrix-inverse, cublas

Since CUDA 5.5, the CUBLAS library contains routines for batched matrix factorization and inversion ([`cublas<t>getrfBatched`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-getrfbatched) and [`cublas<t>getriBatched`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-getribatched) respectively).

Getting guide from the documentation, I wrote a test code for inversion of an N x N matrix using these routines. The code gives correct output only if the matrix has all non zero pivots. Setting any pivot to zero results in incorrect results. I have verified the results using MATLAB.

I realize that I am providing row major matrices as input while CUBLAS expects column major matrices, but it shouldn't matter as it would only transpose the result. To be sure, I also tested on column major input, but getting same behavior.

I am confused as, `cublas<t>getriBatched` expects pivot exchange information array `P` as input, which is the output from `cublas<t>getrfBatched`. So, if any zero pivots are eliminated by row exchange, then the inversion routine should handle it automatically.

How to perform inversion of matrices which contain a zero pivot using CUBLAS?

Following is a self contained compile-able example with different test cases:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#define cudacall(call)                                                                                                          \
    do                                                                                                                          \
    {                                                                                                                           \
        cudaError_t err = (call);                                                                                               \
        if(cudaSuccess != err)                                                                                                  \
        {                                                                                                                       \
            fprintf(stderr,"CUDA Error:\nFile = %s\nLine = %d\nReason = %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err));    \
            cudaDeviceReset();                                                                                                  \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                 \
        }                                                                                                                       \
    }                                                                                                                           \
    while (0)

#define cublascall(call)                                                                                        \
    do                                                                                                          \
    {                                                                                                           \
        cublasStatus_t status = (call);                                                                         \
        if(CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS != status)                                                                     \
        {                                                                                                       \
            fprintf(stderr,"CUBLAS Error:\nFile = %s\nLine = %d\nCode = %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, status);     \
            cudaDeviceReset();                                                                                  \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                 \
        }                                                                                                       \
                                                                                                                \
    }                                                                                                           \
    while(0)


void invert_device(float* src_d, float* dst_d, int n)
{
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublascall(cublasCreate_v2(&handle));

    int batchSize = 1;

    int *P, *INFO;

    cudacall(cudaMalloc<int>(&P,n * batchSize * sizeof(int)));
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<int>(&INFO,batchSize * sizeof(int)));

    int lda = n;

    float *A[] = { src_d };
    float** A_d;
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float*>(&A_d,sizeof(A)));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(A_d,A,sizeof(A),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    cublascall(cublasSgetrfBatched(handle,n,A_d,lda,P,INFO,batchSize));

    int INFOh = 0;
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(&INFOh,INFO,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    if(INFOh == n)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Factorization Failed: Matrix is singular\n");
        cudaDeviceReset();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    float* C[] = { dst_d };
    float** C_d;
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float*>(&C_d,sizeof(C)));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(C_d,C,sizeof(C),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    cublascall(cublasSgetriBatched(handle,n,A_d,lda,P,C_d,lda,INFO,batchSize));

    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(&INFOh,INFO,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    if(INFOh != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Inversion Failed: Matrix is singular\n");
        cudaDeviceReset();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cudaFree(P), cudaFree(INFO), cublasDestroy_v2(handle);
}

void invert(float* src, float* dst, int n)
{
    float* src_d, *dst_d;

    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float>(&src_d,n * n * sizeof(float)));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(src_d,src,n * n * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float>(&dst_d,n * n * sizeof(float)));

    invert_device(src_d,dst_d,n);

    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(dst,dst_d,n * n * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    cudaFree(src_d), cudaFree(dst_d);
}

void test_invert()
{
    const int n = 3;

    //Random matrix with full pivots
    float full_pivots[n*n] = { 0.5, 3, 4, 
                                1, 3, 10, 
                                4 , 9, 16 };

    //Almost same as above matrix with first pivot zero
    float zero_pivot[n*n] = { 0, 3, 4, 
                              1, 3, 10,
                              4 , 9, 16 };

    float zero_pivot_col_major[n*n] = { 0, 1, 4, 
                                        3, 3, 9,
                                        4 , 10, 16 };

    float another_zero_pivot[n*n] = { 0, 3, 4, 
                                      1, 5, 6,
                                      9, 8, 2 };

    float another_full_pivot[n * n] = { 22, 3, 4, 
                                        1, 5, 6,
                                        9, 8, 2 };

    float singular[n*n] = {1,2,3,
                           4,5,6,
                           7,8,9};


    //Select matrix by setting "a"
    float* a = zero_pivot;  

    fprintf(stdout, "Input:\n\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            fprintf(stdout,"%f\t",a[i*n+j]);
        fprintf(stdout,"\n");
    }

    fprintf(stdout,"\n\n");

    invert(a,a,n);

    fprintf(stdout, "Inverse:\n\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            fprintf(stdout,"%f\t",a[i*n+j]);
        fprintf(stdout,"\n");
    }

}

int main()
{
    test_invert();

    int n;  scanf("%d",&n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RobertCrovella... Thankyou for your input. I am facing same behavior with CUDA 5.5 as well as CUDA 6.0 RC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the current CUBLAS library implementation of `cublas<t>getrfBatched` for matrices of dimension (`n`) such that `3<=n<=16`, when there is a "zero pivot" as you say.

A possible workaround is to "identity-extend" your `A` matrix to be inverted, when n<17, to a size of 17x17 (using matlab nomenclature):

```
 LU = getrf( [A 0 ; 0 I]);
```

continuing, you can then use `cublas<t>getriBatched` in an "ordinary" fashion:

```
 invA = getri( LU(1:3,1:3) )
```

(You can also leave everything at n=17, call `getri` that way, and then extract the result as the first 3x3 rows and columns of `invA`.)

Here is a fully worked example, borrowing from the code you supplied, showing the inversion of your supplied 3x3 `zero_pivot` matrix, using the `zero_pivot_war` matrix as an "identity-extended" workaround:

```
$ cat t340.cu
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#define cudacall(call)                                                                                                          \
    do                                                                                                                          \
    {                                                                                                                           \
        cudaError_t err = (call);                                                                                               \
        if(cudaSuccess != err)                                                                                                  \
        {                                                                                                                       \
            fprintf(stderr,"CUDA Error:\nFile = %s\nLine = %d\nReason = %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err));    \
            cudaDeviceReset();                                                                                                  \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                 \
        }                                                                                                                       \
    }                                                                                                                           \
    while (0)

#define cublascall(call)                                                                                        \
    do                                                                                                          \
    {                                                                                                           \
        cublasStatus_t status = (call);                                                                         \
        if(CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS != status)                                                                     \
        {                                                                                                       \
            fprintf(stderr,"CUBLAS Error:\nFile = %s\nLine = %d\nCode = %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, status);     \
            cudaDeviceReset();                                                                                  \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                 \
        }                                                                                                       \
                                                                                                                \
    }                                                                                                           \
    while(0)


void invert_device(float* src_d, float* dst_d, int n)
{
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublascall(cublasCreate_v2(&handle));

    int batchSize = 1;

    int *P, *INFO;

    cudacall(cudaMalloc<int>(&P,17 * batchSize * sizeof(int)));
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<int>(&INFO,batchSize * sizeof(int)));

    int lda = 17;

    float *A[] = { src_d };
    float** A_d;
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float*>(&A_d,sizeof(A)));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(A_d,A,sizeof(A),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    cublascall(cublasSgetrfBatched(handle,17,A_d,lda,P,INFO,batchSize));

    int INFOh = 0;
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(&INFOh,INFO,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    if(INFOh == 17)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Factorization Failed: Matrix is singular\n");
        cudaDeviceReset();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    float* C[] = { dst_d };
    float** C_d;
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float*>(&C_d,sizeof(C)));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(C_d,C,sizeof(C),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    cublascall(cublasSgetriBatched(handle,n,A_d,lda,P,C_d,n,INFO,batchSize));

    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(&INFOh,INFO,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    if(INFOh != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Inversion Failed: Matrix is singular\n");
        cudaDeviceReset();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cudaFree(P), cudaFree(INFO), cublasDestroy_v2(handle);
}

void invert(float* src, float* dst, int n)
{
    float* src_d, *dst_d;

    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float>(&src_d,17 * 17 * sizeof(float)));
    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(src_d,src,17 * 17 * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    cudacall(cudaMalloc<float>(&dst_d,n * n * sizeof(float)));

    invert_device(src_d,dst_d,n);

    cudacall(cudaMemcpy(dst,dst_d,n * n * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    cudaFree(src_d), cudaFree(dst_d);
}

void test_invert()
{
    const int n = 3;

    //Random matrix with full pivots
/*    float full_pivots[n*n] = { 0.5, 3, 4,
                                1, 3, 10,
                                4 , 9, 16 };

    //Almost same as above matrix with first pivot zero
    float zero_pivot[n*n] = { 0, 3, 4,
                              1, 3, 10,
                              4 , 9, 16 };

    float zero_pivot_col_major[n*n] = { 0, 1, 4,
                                        3, 3, 9,
                                        4 , 10, 16 };
*/
    float zero_pivot_war[17*17] = {
                                        0,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        1,3,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        4,9,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 };
/*
    float another_zero_pivot[n*n] = { 0, 3, 4,
                                      1, 5, 6,
                                      9, 8, 2 };

    float another_full_pivot[n * n] = { 22, 3, 4,
                                        1, 5, 6,
                                        9, 8, 2 };

    float singular[n*n] = {1,2,3,
                           4,5,6,
                           7,8,9};
*/
    float result[n*n];

    //Select matrix by setting "a"
    float* a = zero_pivot_war;

    fprintf(stdout, "Input:\n\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            fprintf(stdout,"%f\t",a[i*17+j]);
        fprintf(stdout,"\n");
    }

    fprintf(stdout,"\n\n");

    invert(a,result,n);

    fprintf(stdout, "Inverse:\n\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            fprintf(stdout,"%f\t",result[i*n+j]);
        fprintf(stdout,"\n");
    }

}

int main()
{
    test_invert();

//    int n;  scanf("%d",&n);
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t340 t340.cu -lcublas
$ cuda-memcheck ./t340
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Input:

0.000000        3.000000        4.000000
1.000000        3.000000        10.000000
4.000000        9.000000        16.000000


Inverse:

-0.700000       -0.200000       0.300000
0.400000        -0.266667       0.066667
-0.050000       0.200000        -0.050000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

The above result appears to me to be correct based on a simple test [elsewhere](http://www.quickmath.com/webMathematica3/quickmath/matrices/inverse/basic.jsp).

I don't have any further technical details about the nature of the possible bug in CUBLAS.  From what I can tell, it is present in both CUDA 5.5 and CUDA 6.0 RC.  Detailed bug discussions for NVIDIA-supplied assets (e.g. CUBLAS library) should be taken up on [the NVIDIA developer forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/) or directly at the bug filing portal on [developer.nvidia.com](https://developer.nvidia.com/) (you must be a registered developer to file a bug).

Comment: Superb! Thankyou very much for the workaround. I am getting correct output now. I hope the bug gets fixed soon! :)

Comment: This appears to be fixed in CUDA 6 production release (6.0.37 on linux) which is [now available](http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda)

Comment: Thanks. I tested on windows. The bug is fixed and gives perfect result. :)

Comment: note that with newer versions of CUBLAS, it may be necessary to cast the `A_d` parameter passed to the `getriBatched` function with `(const float **)` for compliance with the newer API.

Comment: @RobertCrovella that' why I have this error

inverse.cu:70:97: error: invalid conversion from ‘float**’ to ‘const float**’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cublas_api.h:2546:16: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘cublasStatus_t cublasSgetriBatched(cublasHandle_t, int, const float**, int, const int*, float**, int, int*, int)’ [-fpermissive]