# cublasSgetriBatched compilation error with CUDA 7.0 Release Candidate

Tags: cuda, cublas

Consider the code posted by sgarizvi at

[CUBLAS: Incorrect inversion for matrix with zero pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887167/cublas-incorrect-inversion-for-matrix-with-zero-pivot)

I'm using that code as an off-the-shelf reproducer of my problem.

If I compile it with CUDA 6.0, everything works fine. Opposite to that, if I compile it with CUDA 6.5 or CUDA 7.0 Release Candidate I receive:

```
Error   13  error C2664: 'cublasSgetriBatched' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'float **' to 'const float *[]'    C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\StackOverflow15\StackOverflow15\kernel.cu   70  1   StackOverflow15
```

Is it a bug or I'm doing anything bad?

My configuration: Windows 7, Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, Release Mode, x64, compute_20,sm_21.

**EDIT**

Following Robert Crovella's answer and Park Young-Bae's comment, the pointed example can be fixed to work with CUDA 6.5 or 7.0 by changing the line

```
cublascall(cublasSgetriBatched(handle,n,A_d,lda,P,C_d,lda,INFO,batchSize));
```

to

```
cublascall(cublasSgetriBatched(handle,n,(const float **)A_d,lda,P,C_d,lda,INFO,batchSize));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried on Windows, but I observe on Linux that the compile error occurs whether I use CUDA 6.5 or CUDA 7 RC.  However if I go back to CUDA 6.0 (which the linked previous question primarily has in view), then the compile error goes away.

There was a change in the CUBLAS API in this respect, in particular for the `getriBatched` function prototype in `cublas_api.h`:

CUDA 6.0:

```
/* Batched inversion based on LU factorization from getrf */
CUBLASAPI cublasStatus_t CUBLASWINAPI cublasSgetriBatched(cublasHandle_t handle,
                                                  int n,
                                                  float *A[],                     /*Device pointer*/
                                                  int lda,
                                                  int *P,                         /*Device pointer*/
                                                  float *C[],                     /*Device pointer*/
                                                  int ldc,
                                                  int *INFO,
                                                  int batchSize);
```

CUDA 6.5/7RC:

```
/* Batched inversion based on LU factorization from getrf */
CUBLASAPI cublasStatus_t CUBLASWINAPI cublasSgetriBatched(cublasHandle_t handle,
                                                  int n,
                                                  const float *A[],               /*Device pointer*/
                                                  int lda,
                                                  const int *P,                   /*Device pointer*/
                                                  float *C[],                     /*Device pointer*/
                                                  int ldc,
                                                  int *info,
                                                  int batchSize);
```

Note the addition of the `const` qualifier on the 3rd parameter.  This is fundamentally what is giving rise to the observed difference.  And as for the actual error itself, this is correct per C++ rules, as indicated by @ParkYoungBae in the comments.

The original code in the previous linked question should be modified for use with newer CUBLAS API headers.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Following your answer and Park Young-Bae's comment, I have edited my post providing a simple line on how fixing my issue.