# Detecting nearly singular matrix in CUDA

Tags: cuda, cublas

I am trying to get inverse of many matrices, which is in the end to find solutions to the system.

I am doing this via the sequence of these CUBLAS function calls,

```
/*
Aims to solve Ax = RHS;
x = Ainv * RHS;
*/

cublas<t>getrfBatched  // to find LU decomposition of A
cublas<t>getriBatched  // to get inverse Ainv
cublas<t>gemmBatched   // to multiply Ainv to RHS, to get the solution
```

While `cublas<t>getrfBatched` will tell whether the given matrix is singular or not, it seems that it does not detect nearly singular matrix (which is mathematically singular, but not singular on a computer due to truncations, etc).

The direct example is

```
A = [[1 , 2 , 3],
     [4 , 5 , 6],
     [7 , 8 , 9]];
```

While cublas detect singularity for `transpose(A)`, but it does not detect singularity for `A`. In fact, Python Numpy also does not detect singularity for `A` and I expect it is due to similar algorithms for LU decomposition and so on.

How I would be able to detect singular matrice in a robust way on CUDA?

***Added***

This is the lines of the code that I used for this example.

```
//base - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887167/cublas-incorrect-inversion-for-matrix-with-zero-pivot

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

#define N 3
#define IDX2C(i,j,ld) (((j)*(ld))+(i))

int main() {

  const int numMat = 6;

  double h_A1[N*N];
  double h_A2[N*N];
  double h_A3[N*N];
  double h_A4[N*N];
  double h_A5[N*N];
  double h_A6[N*N];
  h_A1[IDX2C(0,0,N)] = 0.5; h_A1[IDX2C(0,1,N)] = 3. ; h_A1[IDX2C(0,2,N)] = 4. ;
  h_A1[IDX2C(1,0,N)] = 1. ; h_A1[IDX2C(1,1,N)] = 3. ; h_A1[IDX2C(1,2,N)] = 10.;
  h_A1[IDX2C(2,0,N)] = 4. ; h_A1[IDX2C(2,1,N)] = 9. ; h_A1[IDX2C(2,2,N)] = 16.;

  h_A2[IDX2C(0,0,N)] = 0. ; h_A2[IDX2C(0,1,N)] = 3. ; h_A2[IDX2C(0,2,N)] = 4. ;
  h_A2[IDX2C(1,0,N)] = 1. ; h_A2[IDX2C(1,1,N)] = 3. ; h_A2[IDX2C(1,2,N)] = 10.;
  h_A2[IDX2C(2,0,N)] = 4. ; h_A2[IDX2C(2,1,N)] = 9. ; h_A2[IDX2C(2,2,N)] = 16.;

  h_A3[IDX2C(0,0,N)] = 0. ; h_A3[IDX2C(0,1,N)] = 1. ; h_A3[IDX2C(0,2,N)] = 4. ;
  h_A3[IDX2C(1,0,N)] = 3. ; h_A3[IDX2C(1,1,N)] = 3. ; h_A3[IDX2C(1,2,N)] = 9. ;
  h_A3[IDX2C(2,0,N)] = 4. ; h_A3[IDX2C(2,1,N)] = 10.; h_A3[IDX2C(2,2,N)] = 16.;

  h_A4[IDX2C(0,0,N)] = 0. ; h_A4[IDX2C(0,1,N)] = 3. ; h_A4[IDX2C(0,2,N)] = 4. ;
  h_A4[IDX2C(1,0,N)] = 1. ; h_A4[IDX2C(1,1,N)] = 5. ; h_A4[IDX2C(1,2,N)] = 6. ;
  h_A4[IDX2C(2,0,N)] = 9. ; h_A4[IDX2C(2,1,N)] = 8. ; h_A4[IDX2C(2,2,N)] = 2. ;

  h_A5[IDX2C(0,0,N)] = 22.; h_A5[IDX2C(0,1,N)] = 3. ; h_A5[IDX2C(0,2,N)] = 4. ;
  h_A5[IDX2C(1,0,N)] = 1. ; h_A5[IDX2C(1,1,N)] = 5. ; h_A5[IDX2C(1,2,N)] = 6. ;
  h_A5[IDX2C(2,0,N)] = 9. ; h_A5[IDX2C(2,1,N)] = 8. ; h_A5[IDX2C(2,2,N)] = 2. ;

  h_A6[IDX2C(0,0,N)] = 1. ; h_A6[IDX2C(0,1,N)] = 2. ; h_A6[IDX2C(0,2,N)] = 3. ;
  h_A6[IDX2C(1,0,N)] = 4. ; h_A6[IDX2C(1,1,N)] = 5. ; h_A6[IDX2C(1,2,N)] = 6. ;
  h_A6[IDX2C(2,0,N)] = 7. ; h_A6[IDX2C(2,1,N)] = 8. ; h_A6[IDX2C(2,2,N)] = 9. ;

  double h_rhs[N*N];
  h_rhs[IDX2C(0,0,N)] = 1.; h_rhs[IDX2C(0,1,N)] = 1.; h_rhs[IDX2C(0,2,N)] = 1.;
  h_rhs[IDX2C(1,0,N)] = 2.; h_rhs[IDX2C(1,1,N)] = 2.; h_rhs[IDX2C(1,2,N)] = 2.;
  h_rhs[IDX2C(2,0,N)] = 3.; h_rhs[IDX2C(2,1,N)] = 3.; h_rhs[IDX2C(2,2,N)] = 3.;

  for (int i=0; i<N*N; i++) { printf("%f ", h_rhs[i]); }
  printf("\n");

  double h_sol1[N*N];
  double h_sol2[N*N];
  double h_sol3[N*N];
  double h_sol4[N*N];
  double h_sol5[N*N];
  double h_sol6[N*N];

  double h_inv1[N*N];
  double h_inv2[N*N];
  double h_inv3[N*N];
  double h_inv4[N*N];
  double h_inv5[N*N];
  double h_inv6[N*N];

  double *h_APtr[numMat], *h_AinvPtr[numMat], *h_SolPtr[numMat];
  h_APtr[0] = &(h_A1[0]);
  h_APtr[1] = &(h_A2[0]);
  h_APtr[2] = &(h_A3[0]);
  h_APtr[3] = &(h_A4[0]);
  h_APtr[4] = &(h_A5[0]);
  h_APtr[5] = &(h_A6[0]);

  h_AinvPtr[0] = &(h_inv1[0]);
  h_AinvPtr[1] = &(h_inv2[0]);
  h_AinvPtr[2] = &(h_inv3[0]);
  h_AinvPtr[3] = &(h_inv4[0]);
  h_AinvPtr[4] = &(h_inv5[0]);
  h_AinvPtr[5] = &(h_inv6[0]);

  h_SolPtr[0] = &(h_sol1[0]);
  h_SolPtr[1] = &(h_sol2[0]);
  h_SolPtr[2] = &(h_sol3[0]);
  h_SolPtr[3] = &(h_sol4[0]);
  h_SolPtr[4] = &(h_sol5[0]);
  h_SolPtr[5] = &(h_sol6[0]);

  // allocation
  double *d_A[numMat], *d_Ainv[numMat];  // on Host 
  double **d_APtr, **d_AinvPtr;          // d_A version of Device
  for (int i=0; i<numMat; i++) {
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A[i],    N*N*sizeof(double)); // elements of d_A gets allocated on Device
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Ainv[i], N*N*sizeof(double));
  }
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_APtr,    numMat*sizeof(double *));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_AinvPtr, numMat*sizeof(double *));

  double *d_Rhs[numMat], *d_Sol[numMat]; 
  double **d_RhsPtr, **d_SolPtr;
  for (int i=0; i<numMat; i++) {
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Rhs[i], N*N*sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Sol[i], N*N*sizeof(double));
  }
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_RhsPtr, numMat*sizeof(double *));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_SolPtr, numMat*sizeof(double *));

  int *P, *INFO; // specific to cublas<t>getrfBatched
  cudaMalloc(&P,   N*numMat*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(&INFO,  numMat*sizeof(int));

  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");

  // memcpy
  for (int i=0; i<numMat; i++) {
    cudaMemcpy(d_A[i], h_APtr[i], N*N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  }
  cudaMemcpy(d_APtr,    d_A,    numMat*sizeof(double *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_AinvPtr, d_Ainv, numMat*sizeof(double *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  for (int i=0; i<numMat; i++) {
    cudaMemcpy(d_Rhs[i], h_rhs, N*N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  }
  cudaMemcpy(d_RhsPtr, d_Rhs, numMat*sizeof(double *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_SolPtr, d_Sol, numMat*sizeof(double *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy H2D fail");

  // CUBLAS
  cublasHandle_t myhandle;
  cublasStatus_t cublas_result;

  cublas_result = cublasCreate_v2(&myhandle);
  assert(cublas_result == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS);

  // getrfBatched
  cublasDgetrfBatched(myhandle, N, d_APtr, N, P, INFO, numMat);
  assert(cublas_result == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS);

  int INFOh[numMat];
  cudaMemcpy(&INFOh, INFO, numMat*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy H2D fail (2)");

  for (int i=0; i<numMat; i++) {
    if (INFOh[i] != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: something wrong in INFOh\n");
      fprintf(stderr, " - batch %d, INFO %d\n", i, INFOh[i]);
    }
  }

  // getriBatched
  cublasDgetriBatched(myhandle, N, d_APtr, N, P, d_AinvPtr, N, INFO, numMat);
  assert(cublas_result == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS);

  cudaMemcpy(&INFOh, INFO, numMat*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy H2D fail (3)");

  // print inverse
  printf("\n Inverses \n");
  for (int i=0; i<numMat; i++) {
    cudaMemcpy(h_AinvPtr[i], d_Ainv[i], N*N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  }
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy D2H fail");

  double *tmpptr, *tmpptrInv;
  for (int k=0; k<numMat; k++) {
    tmpptr    = h_APtr[k];
    tmpptrInv = h_AinvPtr[k];

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
        printf("%f\t", tmpptr[IDX2C(i,j,N)]);
      }

      for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
        printf("%f\t", tmpptrInv[IDX2C(i,j,N)]);
      }

      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  // gemmBatched
  double alpha = 1.0;
  double beta  = 0.0;
  cublas_result = cublasDgemmBatched(myhandle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N,
                                     N,N,N,
                                     &alpha, d_AinvPtr, N, d_RhsPtr, N,
                                     &beta,  d_SolPtr,  N,
                                     numMat);
  assert(cublas_result == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS);

  cudaFree(P);
  cudaFree(INFO);
  cublasDestroy_v2(myhandle);

  // print solution
  printf("\n Solutions \n");
  for (int i=0; i<numMat; i++) {
    cudaMemcpy(h_SolPtr[i], d_Sol[i], N*N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_A[i]);
    cudaFree(d_Ainv[i]);
  }
  cudaFree(d_APtr);
  cudaFree(d_AinvPtr);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy D2H fail (2)");

  for (int k=0; k<numMat; k++) {
    tmpptr    = h_APtr[k];
    tmpptrInv = h_SolPtr[k];

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
        printf("%f\t", tmpptr[IDX2C(i,j,N)]);
      }

      for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
        printf("%f\t", tmpptrInv[IDX2C(i,j,N)]);
      }

      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This code is messy, and maybe some allocations are not properly freed till the end of the code (I had put more focus on make it run and understand the CUBLAS application). I do not want you to read through this messy code, just wanted to demonstrate indeed CUBLAS does not detect singular matrix in some cases with directly compilable, and runable set of code lines.

It solves batched 6 systems, each of them consists of 3x3 A, and share the same 3x3 RHS.

It is the `h_A6` which should be detected as singular.

When I run this, the result looks like

```
...
Inverses
...
1.000000    2.000000    3.000000    3152519739159346.500000 -6305039478318690.000000    3152519739159346.000000 
4.000000    5.000000    6.000000    -6305039478318695.000000    12610078956637384.000000    -6305039478318692.000000
7.000000    8.000000    9.000000    3152519739159348.000000 -6305039478318693.000000    3152519739159346.000000
```

We can see that for some singular matrix, it gives absurd result even with double precision.

Comment: What type are you using to represent these numbers?

Comment: @talonmies, Both single or double precision gives absurd results for the (nearly) singular matrix. I have posted the code I used.

Comment: If the matrices are really omly 3×3, you could always analytically calculate the determinant and apply whatever tolerance you think is required to define singularity

Comment: @talonmies, This is just a very reduced version of my actual application. In my application, I will use 9x9 matrices with batchSize of tens of million. While I do not expect singular matrices emerge in my application, I thought I'd better have some safe guard which I can turn on at least for debugging purpose

Comment: I don't understand. If your question is really " I'm calculating matrix inverse for a batch of 9x9 double precision matrices with cublas and occasionally ill-conditoned cases cause blow-up because of near singularity. Is there something I  an do to catch these?" Why no just ask it? Why do we have to ask for details all the time?

Comment: @talonmies, My main question was - as is written in the question already - "How I would be able to detect singular matrice in a robust way on CUDA?".  Since SO usually asks me to narrow down the question with minimum reproducible examples, I did it with a smaller 3x3 system to ultimately ask for a robust way to catch singularities. If this "main question" was quite hidden, hard to read at a glance in the end of the lengthy 3x3 reduced question, I apologise. But I do not see your point this time, while I appreciate your contributions to SO and learned a lot from your answers in other posts.

Comment: The size of the problem is significant since inverting small matrices is directly possible. In plenty of these questions, we have to check whether people miss the obvious. Anyway, sounds like you just want to compute the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices)

Answer (score 1):

The conventional diagnostic to use in this situation is the [condition number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of the matrix. LAPACK offers [GECON](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d9a/group__double_g_ecomputational_ga188b8d30443d14b1a3f7f8331d87ae60.html) for this purpose, and it shouldn’t be particularly difficult to implement your own version using the LU factorisation you are already calculating.